# Why github have a limit on users? Can other users sync from the other user repo?

Tags: git, github

If I understand correctly one of the advantages of Git is that everybody has the full repository.
This allows one person to get a repository and once he has that repository, another person can come and sync with the first person without the need of going to the main repo.

In Github some plans are limited to 5 collaborators or 10 collaborators.
That this means that only 5 person can sync with the main repository?  or other persons can also sync from other people without any issues?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a limitation for a private repo.  It means 5 people can collaborate on that project (ex: use the wiki/issue tracker/push/pull/fork within github)

Once you have your own local clone of the repo, you can push it wherever you want and give anyone permission to clone it, but you have to do it "outside" the github environment.

Answer (score 1):

That limitation is for the number of users that can commit to your private repository. It is not a limitation of how many people can pull, clone, or fork your public repos.

Also, understand that this has nothing to do with Git as a tool, it is only a limitation imposed by GitHub as a company in order to generate a revenue plan.